# Have firestore put document ID in a struct property

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible when adding document to firestore with go to have the ID of that document stored in one of the properties of the added struct ?

```
type MyStruct struct {
    ID          string    `json:"id" firestore:"id,omitempty"`
}
```

I would like the ID of the document to be in the ID of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) documentation, you can see that is possible to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later by using the call to `.doc()`, there is also an example using Go on how to do that.

You could use that to fetch the ID of the document and add it to the other fields of the struct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that part, but I wanted to know if its possible to have the ID of the document stored in a property of the persisted struct.

Comment: You could set up a snapshot listener to update your struct objects on the onCreate event of the document, I am not sure how to that in go though...

Comment: That’s the only way ? Another dB op ?

Comment: I would say that it is possible that there are other ways to do it, however, using the  snapshot listener would be the recommended and more efficient way to do it.